# Validate a json Object against a raml datatype in mule 3.9

Tags: validation, mule, raml

Is there a mechanism in Mule 3.9.x for validating that a JSON entity is a valid instance of a specific RAML datatype, without manually generating and maintaining JSON-schema files and including them in the project?

The APIKit router does performs this kind of validation, but also requires that the  incoming message contains other REST information, such as resource path and http Method.

I would like to use this to validate the input payloads of non http endpoints (JMS, amqp, etc) as well as a postcondition of REST APIs (to sooner find violations of RAML contracts in testing and lower environments)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. You can Create JSON Schema using this link https://jsonschema.net/ and use it on the JSON Schema validator Component In Mule Flow.

```
<json:validate-schema schemaLocation="myJsonSchema.json" doc:name="Validate JSON Schema"/>
```

Comment: So i need to generate and maintain a json-schema file with every raml update, and include this in the mule project? My question is if there is a way to avoid doing this. The apikit router manages to do it without, is it available without full request validation/routing?

Comment: If you want to validate some part of the json that stays imutable a solution i can think of on top of my head is using a dataweave script to return true if the fields are not null and then doing a choice based on that. Also you have to disable raml validation or remove the schema from the raml.